# Increase image filesize, without changing the resolution

Tags: affinity-designer

I've got a bit of a tricky question.

For an agency I need to deliver an image with an minimal file size of 2 MB and with an minimal resolution of 1418px in width.

The photo I've is 1418 x 1418 png image with an file size of 378kB. It contains a white background. I think that's why the file size is so small.

The resolution of my image is high enough, but they want an bigger file size. (I've no clue why!)

Is there a way to increase the file size without changing something to the image?

I'm using Affinity Designer, Affinity Photo and Gimp.

Comment: Add an invisibly light grain to that white background. That will defeat PNGs pattern-seeking compression algorithms. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Gimp** we can export an image with either choosing an uncompressed PNG format or any other uncompressed image format (e.g. BMP, TIF) to increase filesize. Below shows setting for `0` compressed PNG:

[image]

If the file size still was too small we may have an indexed source file that can further be expanded on converting it to RGB.

Comment: Wow! The file went from 378kB to 5,76MB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason they want something bigger than 2MB is the presumption that anything smaller will have used some form of lossy compression.

Using Affinity Designer, or Photo, export as an uncompressed Tiff file (or PNG) file is not possible. They're always compressed, but it's not a lossy compression - that which the agency fears.

So you're going to have to convince the receiver of your files that you're using a non-lossy compression. The easiest way to do this is to send them a TIFF file from Photoshop, without compression, of the same Affinity Designer/Photo, with your png file from Affinity, and let them check. This should put them at rest for the future.

If you don't have access to Photoshop, you're going to need find another way to convince them. Perhaps call them and lambast them, or find something on the Affinity sites that indicates their TIFF and PNG exports are not lossy, but do lossless compression.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just send an uncompressed Tiff file. But I'm afraid it's not gonna work out. And it still does not solve my initial question.